# Self-joining thread pool: where's my race condition?

Tags: python, multithreading, race-condition, python-multithreading, worker

Since I use a similar pattern in my work a lot, I decided to write a class that abstracts very simple worker concurrency via job queue / threading. I know there are already things out there that solve this, but I also wanted to use this as an opportunity to hone my multithreading skills.

The main challenge I've given myself is that I want this to be able to let processes finish, even if they are not explicitly blocked by Queue.join(). "A process finishing" is defined by the input function returning a value (or None). The way I have attempted to accomplish this is by having each job create it's own results queue `rq`, which is then checked by `_wait_for_results` in a non-daemon thread, which blocks the automatic exit of all other daemonized threads until `rq` is filled by the worker in `add_to_queue`.

Here is the full class:

```
class EasyPool(object):
    def __init__(self, concurrency, always_finish=True):
        def add_to_queue(q):
            while True:
                func_data, rq = q.get()
                func, args, kwargs = func_data
                if not args:
                    args = []
                if not kwargs:
                    kwargs = {}
                result = func(*args, **kwargs)
                rq.put(result)
                q.task_done()

        self.rqs = []
        self.always_finish = always_finish
        self.q = Queue(maxsize=0)
        self.workers = []
        for i in range(concurrency):
            worker = Thread(target=add_to_queue, args=(self.q,))
            self.workers.append(worker)
            worker.setDaemon(True)
            worker.start()

    def _wait_for_results(self, rq):
        rq.not_empty.acquire()
        rq.not_empty.wait()
        rq.not_empty.notify()
        rq.not_empty.release()

    def add_job(self, func, *args, **kwargs):
        rq = Queue()
        if self.always_finish:
            blocker = Thread(target=self._wait_for_results, args=(rq,))
            blocker.setDaemon(False)
            blocker.start()
        to_add = []
        [ to_add.append(i) if i else to_add.append(None) for i in [func, args, kwargs] ]
        self.q.put((to_add, rq))
        return rq.get
```

When a job is created via the `.add_job` instance method, it immediately returns a promise-like object, which is a reference to the `.get` method of the results queue. The problem I'm facing is that there seems to be a race condition between this `.get` and the `_wait_for_results` method. I think the answer probably involves a Lock or a Condition, but I'm not really sure. Any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: Your list comprehension currently works via side effects which is... not usually preferred. In this case, you could just do `to_add = [i or None for i in [func,args,kwargs]]`. You might also wan to look at the `concurrent.futures` stdlib module - even if you want to roll your own, it might help you find any edge cases you're missing.

Comment: Why are you waiting for results in the first place? The `rq.get` you return, once called, should wait until the `rq.put(result)` happens.

Comment: @MathiasEttinger, please refer to my second paragraph. If the script reaches the EOF and the workers are not finished, I need to use `Queue.join()`, or some other blocking method so it doesn't cut them off. I am trying to avoid using `.join()` to accomplish this, so that even if the EOF is reached, it still finishes the jobs.

Comment: In other words, if the promise functions returned are never called when EOF is reached, they should still complete.